# Insert bulk of records into MySQL with stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I have some millions records and I want to insert them as some batches to increase the speed.

I have a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `source_names` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `source_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `source_name_UNIQUE` (`source_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=39 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and in one step I want to add 500 `source_name` in `source_names` like this:

```
insert ignore into source_names (source_name) 
values ('a01'),('a02'),...,('a500')
```

up to here there is no problem.

In `Qt` I have a `QString` which is like this (of course the IDE is not important in this question):

```
QString totalSourceNames="('a01'),('a02'),...,('a500')";
```

I want to insert this QString into `source_names` table by `insertPro` stored procedure and these commands:

```
query.prepare("CALL insertPro(:source_names)");
query.bindValue(":source_names",totalSourceNames);
query.exec()
```

and my stored procedure is:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insertPro`(
IN source_names text
)
BEGIN
    insert ignore into source_names(source_name) values (source_names);
END
```

By `MySQL` inserts just one row and concatenates all 500 values in one value. I know this is because of parenthesis in front of `values (...)` in above code but removing parenthesis makes an error in MySQL.

How can I insert 500 records with stored procedure?